# Need help parsing results from ldap to csv

Tags: loops, csv, perl, ldap, control-flow

I am trying to create a script to generate a csv file with the results of some ldap queries using Net::LDAP but I'm having troubles skipping incomplete lines if one element of the @attributes array is blank.

```
my @attributes  = ('cn', 'mail', 'telephoneNumber');
```

So for example, if a user has no mail listed, or no telephoneNumber listed, then it should skip the hold field instead of returning:

```
"Foo Bar",, # this line should be skipped since there is no mail nor telephone
"Bar Foo","bar@foo.com", # this line should be skipped too, no number listed
"John Dever","john_dever@google.com","12345657" # this one is fine, has all values
```

My loop right now is looking like this:

```
# Now dump all found entries
while (my $entry = $mesg->shift_entry()){
    # Retrieve each fields value and print it
    # if attr is multivalued, separate each value
    my $current_line = ""; # prepare fresh line
    foreach my $a (@attributes) {
        if ($entry->exists($a)) {
            my $attr = $entry->get_value($a, 'asref' => 1);
            my @values  = @$attr;
            my $val_str = "";
            if (!$singleval) {
                # retrieve all values and separate them via $mvsep
                foreach my $val (@values) {
                    if ($val eq "") { print "empty"; }
                    $val_str = "$val_str$val$mvsep"; # add all values to field
                }
                $val_str =~ s/\Q$mvsep\E$//; # eat last MV-Separator
            } else {
                $val_str = shift(@values); # user wants only the first value
            }

            $current_line .= $fieldquot.$val_str.$fieldquot; # add field data to current line

        }
        $current_line .= $fieldsep; # close field and add to current line
    }
    $current_line =~ s/\Q$fieldsep\E$//; # eat last $fieldsep
    print "$current_line\n"; # print line
}
```

I have tried code like :

```
if ($attr == "") { next; }
if (length($attr) == 0) { next; }
```

and several others without any luck. I also tried simple if () { print "isempty";  } debug tests and its not working. Im not exacly sure how could I do this.

I appreciate any help or pointers you could give me on what am I doing wrong.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

**UPDATE:**
Per chaos request:

```
my $singleval = 0;
```

A sample run for this program would return:

```
Jonathan Hill,Johnathan_Hill@example.com,7883                  
John Williams,John_Williams@example.com,3453                     
Template OAP,,                                            
Test Account,,                                                
Template Contracts,,
```

So what I want to do is to skip all the lines that are missing a field, either email or extension number.

Answer (score 2):

Label your `while` loop:

```
Record: while (my $entry = $mesg->shift_entry()){
```

and use:

```
next Record;
```

Your problem is that your `next` is associated with your `foreach`.  Using the label avoids that.

By the way, `$attr == ''`, though it will work in this case, is bad logic; in perl, `==` is a numeric comparison.  String comparison would be `$attr eq ''`.  Though I'd just use `next Record unless $attr`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of Labeling the while loop and using next Record unless $attr but it is still printing those lines with empty fields.

I appreciate your suggestions very much! I am new to perl and was not aware that I had to use eq instead of == for non numeric values. Thanks for the tip!!!

Comment: You're welcome.  Looking at your code more closely, $attr is an array reference, so that will always be true.  Try next Record unless @$attr;

Comment: that didnt work either :(
also, i tried doing if (@$attr eq "") { print "empty"; } and its not printing empty so I think the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah.  Rereading your post again, it looks like, since you want to skip it if there are any empty values, all you need to do is replace if ($val eq "") { print "empty"; } with next Record unless $val;

Comment: nope, that doesn't work either.
in fact, i left the print statement there and its not printing "empty" when a field is empty. i've been all day trying to debug this with no luck. could it be a bug in perl?

Comment: No, Perl is fine.  The problem seems to be that neither you nor I seem to know how to identify the condition that a value in the list is empty.  Could you edit your post to include the output of a run?  If we can figure out what to tell the code to look for, that should be the whole ball game.

Comment: It'd also be nice to know whether this $singleval variable is on or not.